# Allow chinese characters and English numbers only in textbox - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, unicode

Following is my regex to accept only chinese characters and English numbers in a textbox but its failing for some scenarios like below mentioned. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Regex -**

```
const regex = /[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF0-9]+/g
```

Failing cases -

- 090 asffa
- 0342eq###
- 42242442dsfsfs

React Example code setup - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLQJKM

Comment: Your character set doesn't have space or `#` character and alphabets so they won't match.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi the problem is that **they do** (aparently)  **match**.

Comment: @Kaiido: Aah, in that case using start `^` and end `$` anchors would solve the issue and will avoid partial matching of strings. Use `^[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF0-9]+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is checking if the input contains at least one such character. 
As long as there will be either a number, or a Chinese character, it will consider your input as valid.

What you want is to find if there is any character that **do not** match this pattern. To do so, you simply need to use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^...` and then check if `string.match(regex)` is falsy.

```js
const reg = /[^\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF0-9]+/g;
const test = txt => {
  console.log(txt, !txt.match(reg));
};


test('090 asffa'); // false
test('0342eq###'); // false
test('42242442dsfsfs'); // false
test('foo我'); // false
test('245我吧'); // true
test('245'); // true
test('我吧'); // true
```

Comment: This works great! This is my code as I want to allow English letters as well: `.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF]/, '-')`. The only thing I need changed is filtering out spacing. How would I add that in?

Comment: @user2465134 simply add either the space character ` ` litteraly, or the white-space character `\s` if you also want to allow \t \n etc. directly in the group.